# Asana Refresh Token Url Endpoint

Tags: asana

I can't seem to find the url I'm supposed to use for the asana refresh token.  I know how the flow works on refreshing access_tokens, all I need is the url endpoint.  Does anyone know what it is?

Thanks

Comment: Hey I just found out that it is the same URL as authorization, https://app.asana.com/-/oauth_token.

Comment: They are not the same. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are both the user auth URL and the token exchange URL that can be used to refresh a user's token. Hope that helps.

API base URL https://app.asana.com

- User auth: /-/oauth_authorize
- Token exchange: /-/oauth_token

Found here: https://github.com/Asana/oauth-examples